# Nuxt 3, Cloudflare pages and KV binding

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Trying to get a basic nuxt app or project interact with KV feature of Cloudflare under pages, this is the repo: https://github.com/gmesml/nuxxx, afterwards I set up a page with this repository using npm run build as build command and dist as output directory.

The deployment succeeds and seem to be no issues there:

```
08:53:46.586    ✨ Success! Uploaded 1 files (9 already uploaded) (1.07 sec)
08:53:46.586    
08:53:46.921    ✨ Upload complete!
08:53:48.320    Success: Assets published!
08:53:50.046    Success: Your site was deployed!
```

However visiting the site it shows of: Error 1102 "Worker exceeded resource limits" in nuxt style.

All I seek is having a basic understanding how to interact with binding and have a simple TODO to begin exploration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent update of Cloudflare documentations addresses this matter:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/framework-guides/deploy-a-nuxt-site/#use-bindings-in-your-nuxt-application

At this time, May2023, the author of the framework published real world examples for this stack:

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/deploy-nuxt-ssr-to-cloudflare-workers/275240/5?u=mentorgashi

Comment: Despite this, still do not have it clear on other issues, the devs are busy.